# Flux Handling Action State

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux, refluxjs

When i am correct in flux there are 2 different kinds of state

- Application State (in Stores)
- View State (in the Component)

i am trying to build a CRUD application using flux and don't understand what's the smartest way to deal with action state.

consider i've a page with 2 components that are responsible for creating a blogpost. so a editor could choose if the want to use component1 or component2 to create the blogpost.

by pressing on the save button on component1 the component is sending an BLOGPOST_CREATE_ACTION.

In the component i want to display the lifecycle of the action:

- Sending blogpost to the server
- Blogpost is saved or saving failed

The store can keep track of these states and can emit when it changes.
But as i've 2 different components looking at the same store, the state change would take effect on both of my components.

Flux is build for keeping everything consistent, but in this case i want to get status (including error) informations independent for every component.

How do you deal with such "issues"?

Comment: First of all, I don't have a ready packed solution. But you can add a flag (e.g. part of the component's state) to each component. This flag can be used to determine whether the component has send the 'save' action or not. If not, it can ignore the triggers from the store that is listens to. If the component was responsible for sending the 'save' action. It shouldn't ignore the status update info from the store. The tricky part is to have correct functionality in all possible situations (errors etc.).

Comment: at the moment i try something like this: create a random (i call it) transaction id and log every event (events will be part of the state) with this transaction is. now i can ask for all events using this transaction id, so every component will just get it's messages. feels a bit messy but very powerful